# How to set up managed dependencies in an SBT 0.11 project having Build.scala

Tags: scala, sbt

I am building a simple Scala project with SBT 0.11.

All the code files are in `~/MyProject/src/main/scala/`

`~/MyProject/build.sbt` is the following

```
name := "MyProject"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.+",
  "c3p0" % "c3p0" % "0.9.1.2",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.0.1",
  "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6",
  "javassist" % "javassist" % "3.12.1.GA"
)
```

`~/MyProject/project/Build.scala` is the following

```
import sbt._

object MyProjectBuild extends Build {
  lazy val MyProject = Project("MyProject", file("."))
}
```

This seems to work almost fine. The project does compile and run. The project name is set correctly (if I don't use Build.scala, then the name seems to appear something like "default-????", despite it being specified in build.sbt).

But the problem is that dependencies do not seem to work - `update` command doesn't download anything. How to fix this? Do I need to specify my dependencies in `Build.scala` rather than in `build.sbt` in this case?

Comment: In the title, do you mean `build.sbt` rather than `build.scala`?

Comment: @kipton-barros No. I mean that a project having `Build.scala` in addition to `build.sbt`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is it possible that you've already retrieved the project dependencies, but don't realize it because they are stored in the Ivy cache? You can view the managed classpath from the SBT console with the command

```
show managed-classpath
```

Recent versions of SBT do not store the managed dependencies in the project directory, unless the project is configured to do so. If you want, you can add the following to your `build.sbt` file:

```
retrieveManaged := true
```

This will create a `~/MyProject/lib_managed/` directory and contents.

Comment: But this doesn't copy the scala libraries to lib_managed?! How I can achieve this?

Comment: You might have to run the SBT commands `reload`, `clean` and `update`.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. The `scala-compiler.jar` is still saved ~/.sbt/boot/..., it would be great if this also may be saved at lib_managed.

Comment: @Themerius, I understand your question now. If you want `scala-compiler.jar` you may have to add an explicit dependency. I have this in my `build.sbt`: `libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.9.1")`