# Sbt building distribution for a project

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there an easy way to create a distribution for a SBT project, which collects all dependency jars into a single directory like lib and the main project jar file refers to all its dependencies using manifest entries? It would be nice if one could define a main class.

Answer (score 3):

This [answere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7989565/355499) says how to do part of what you want. Namely get the managed dependencies into `lib_managed` directory. Basically just add:

```
retrieveManaged := true
```

to your build.sbt file.

Alternatively you could look at a One-jar plugin https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar It might do a bit more than you want though.

Comment: not really assembly creation means a lot of manual merge strategies and trouble in jvm world.